# Nested Async/Await function

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs

It's easier just to look at the code:

```
async function addFiles(dir,tree) {
  return (await readDir(dir))
    .map(name => {await readDir(dir); return name;}) // error here
}
```

This code returns an error on line 3, saying there's an unexpected token near `readDir`. I don't understand why this won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, I forgot to declare my arrow function as async.

the revised code is

```
async function addFiles(dir,tree) {
  return (await readDir(dir))
    .map(async name => {await readDir(dir); return name;}) // error here
}
```

Comment: hey, for future reference, I am curious what the implementation you are using this for? from "reading it", looks like you are giving a tree structure and reading the directory under it? Just looking for context, as a go to example in the future :-)

Comment: sure thing...I will post it when I finish getting all the bugs out :)

Comment: as i understand it this is a suboptimal way to do `map` with `async/await`.  if you `await` a `Promise.all`, you utilize a lot more parallel processing. i made a pseudo-code jsfiddle to illustrate using what i think is ur usecase:  https://jsfiddle.net/ry93b8r3/

Comment: Could you please accept your own answer? Doing so will help others who read the question in future. Thanks (and upvote ;-)